# I have an issue with breaking lines in javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with breaking line in javascript. It doen't make a break line in html page, how can i fix this?

[image: Doesn't makes brakes]

```js
let currentDate;

var botHp;
var playerHp;

const postlog = function(message) {
  document.querySelector(".gamelogchat").textContent += message;
};

document.querySelector(".cardbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("click");
  currentDate = new Date();
  let Time =
    currentDate.getHours() +
    ":" +
    currentDate.getMinutes() +
    ":" +
    currentDate.getSeconds();

  postlog(Time + "\r\n");
});
```

```html
<div class="gamelog">
  <h1 class="gamename">Game</h1>
  <p class="gamelogname">Game log</p>

  <div class="gamelogbox">
    <p class="gamelogchat"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `<br>` in HTML to break lines.

Comment: Or set the style of the element to `white-space: pre;`

Comment: This is basic HTML. Don't you know that it normally re-wraps lines?

Comment: Thanks `white-space: pre;` fixed everything. I'm just begginer in html and javascript, i don't know much stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change on

```js
document.querySelector(".gamelogchat").innerHTML += message + "<br />";
```

Mb, it's better to understand with demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-phoebe-9zl3h?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
let currentDate;  
var botHp;  
var playerHp;  

const postlog=function(message)
{
  document.querySelector('.gamelogchat').textContent+=message;
};

document.querySelector('.cardbutton').addEventListener('click',function()
{
  console.log('click');
  currentDate=new Date();
  let Time=currentDate.getHours()+':'+currentDate.getMinutes()+':'+currentDate.getSeconds();    
  postlog(Time+'<br/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem:

```js
let currentDate;

var botHp;
var playerHp;

const postlog = function(message) {
  document.querySelector(".gamelogchat").innerHTML += message;
};

document.querySelector(".cardbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("click");
  currentDate = new Date();
  let Time =
    currentDate.getHours() +
    ":" +
    currentDate.getMinutes() +
    ":" +
    currentDate.getSeconds();

  postlog(Time + "<br>");//\r\n
});
```

```html
<div class="gamelog">
  <h1 class="gamename">Game</h1>
  <p class="gamelogname">Game log</p>

  <button class="cardbutton">Test Button</button>
  <div class="gamelogbox">
    <p class="gamelogchat"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```